# MYSQL- select and join multiple tables into one JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, multiple-tables

Can you please advise how I can fix this query?
I have 3 DB Tables.

1. networks.
2. products.
3. comments.

The query looked like this before I added the "comments" table (worked as expected):

```
SELECT networks.*, products.product, products.type 
FROM products 
JOIN networks ON products.id=networks.product_Id
```

and now I tried modifing it with the additional table, and it doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    networks.*, 
    products.product, 
    products.type, 
    comments.id AS comment_Id, 
    comments.newLine, 
    comments.lineComment AS comment, 
    comments.topComment, 
    comments.bottomComment 
JOIN networks ON products.id=networks.product_Id, 
ON comments.id=networks.comment_Id
```

How can I fix this query?

Thanks for the helpers :)

Comment: What doesn't work?  You've neglected to explain that.  Nor have you explained what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You joined **networks** table with condition **products.id=networks.product_Id**
But for comments table you specified the condition **comments.id=networks.comment_Id** but you forgot to join the **comments** table.

try

```
 SELECT networks.*, 
    products.product, 
    products.type, 
    comments.id AS comment_Id, 
    comments.newLine, 
    comments.lineComment AS comment, 
    comments.topComment, 
    comments.bottomComment 
    FROM products
    JOIN networks ON products.id=networks.product_Id
    JOIN comments ON comments.id=networks.comment_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the syntax you are after:

```
SELECT 
    n.*, 
    p.product, 
    p.type,
    c.id AS comment_id, 
    c.newLine, 
    c.lineComment AS comment, 
    c.topComment, 
    c.bottomComment 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN networks n ON p.id = n.product_id
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.id = n.comment_id
```

That is: the syntax for multiple joins is `FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... JOIN ... ON ...`.

Note that the use of table aliases shortens the query and makes it easier to read and write.